# Value that should be integer becomes NoneType

Tags: python

```
if data["level"] == 4:
  from levels import level_004 as level
  levelreturn = level.level(data)
  addMoney = investSub.tract(levelreturn,data["investorShare"])
  data["money"] += addMoney
```

How come in the `investSub.tract()` function, I get this error?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 101, in <module>
    addMoney = investSub.tract(levelreturn,data["investorShare"])
  File "/home/runner/investSub.py", line 3, in tract
    total = subtotal*netshare
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'float'
```

`Levelreturn` always returns an integer, so I can't seem to find the problem. I checked other questions but that didn't work. If needed, I can provide more code.

EDIT:

```
#level_004.py
import shortcuts as s
def level(saveF):
  s.qp("You and Miranda start selling lemonade to people.")
  if saveF["recipe"] == 0:
    f = 100
    return f
  elif saveF["recipe"] == 1:
    f = 200
    return f
  elif saveF["recipe"] == 2:
    f = -50
    return f
  elif saveF["recipe"] == 3:
    f = 115
    return f
```

Any other questions just let me know.

Comment: We can't reproduce the problem with the code you posted.

Comment: Check your data, if `data['money']` is `None` then obviously it will have this error.

Comment: It's impossible to say what happens in `investSub.tract` if you keep it secret.

Comment: @RockyLi I don't see data['money'] as None.

Comment: @timgeb I added more code

Comment: `def tract(subtotal, investorShare):
  netshare = 1 - investorShare
  total = subtotal*netshare
  return total` <-- @molbdnilo this is the investDub.tract

Comment: If `saveF["recipe"]` is not in {0,1,2,3}, `level` will return `None`.